# How to configure the sync between latex and resulting pdf in AUCTeX?

Tags: auctex, forward-inverse-search

I am running AUCTeX in Emacs 25 (latest version) on arch linux. I have searched some configuration online, but they don't work. Here is the relevant configuration:

```lisp
(setq TeX-view-program-selection
      '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("PDF Viewer" "okular --unique %o#src:%n%b")))
(server-start)
(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape %S%(PDFout)")))
;; use Sumatra PDF to preview pdf
(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
;; Enable synctex generation. Even though the command shows
;; as "latex" pdflatex is actually called
(custom-set-variables '(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1") )
```

What's going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Assuming that you're using AUCTeX 12, can you reduce your configuration to `(server-start)
(setq TeX-view-program-selection
      '((output-pdf "Okular")))
(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)`, restart Emacs and try it again?

Comment: It does work! Thank you sooo much! But why?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have AUCTeX 12 installed, it will be sufficient to replace your configuration with these lines:

```lisp
(server-start)
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular")))
(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
```

The main reason why your configuration doesn't work is this line:

```lisp
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("PDF Viewer" "okular --unique %o#src:%n%b")))
```

AUCTeX has builtin support for Okular, you only need to pick it with `TeX-view-program-list` as mentioned above (see [here for details](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/tex.el#n1400)).

Some comments regarding the rest of your code:

- `(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape %S%(PDFout)")))`
  This one can be considered harmful; it will allow execution of external commands from a .tex file per default.  I suggest you solve this one on a per file basis with a file local variable, e.g.

  ```
  %%% Local Variables:
  %%% mode: latex
  %%% TeX-master: t
  %%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
  %%% End:
  ```
- `(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)`
  Also not really needed, AUCTeX has a sensible default which uses `synctex` with `pdfLaTeX`.
- `(custom-set-variables '(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1") )`
  Again not needed, AUCTeX does that automatically when `TeX-source-correlate-mode` it `t` and `LaTeX-command-style` is not changed.